# Java split is returning an unexpected length?

Tags: java

I'm working on an application that parses a text file with information that is delimited as following:

```
id#title#author
```

There are certain lines that contain no data for the author and are simply blank, however there is still a # at the end. Using Java's built in split, the returned length is only 2. Do I need to manually check the length of the returned array in my function or is there another method?

For example:

```
26380#Complete Story of the San Francisco Horror#
```

I'm trying to return a null value for the author if it is not listed. I'm currently using:

```
data.split("#")
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. Your string is pound delimited? What exactly is the problem again?

Comment: I guess I should ask, is there a simple RegEx I can use to get even empty strings?

Comment: What are you trying to do? You want to output a string that replaces the # with a space? Or put them in separate variables?

Comment: You would need to check the length unless you format your input with the additional # like this `id#title##` then you would have a consistent number of tokens.

Comment: It is pound delimited however, if there is nothing listed for author the length returns 2 instead of 3. I need it to return the null if the author is nonexistent.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I didn't mean to blame the language, I more meant I was unsure of why I was receiving an unexpected value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the overloaded method

```
yourString.split("#", -1)
```

The [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) states

> The array returned by this method contains each substring of this
>   string that is terminated by another substring that matches the given
>   expression or is terminated by the end of the string.
>
> [...]
>
> The limit parameter controls the number of times the pattern is
>   applied and therefore affects the length of the resulting array. If
>   the limit n is greater than zero then the pattern will be applied at
>   most n - 1 times, the array's length will be no greater than n, and
>   the array's last entry will contain all input beyond the last matched
>   delimiter. **If n is non-positive then the pattern will be applied as
>   many times as possible and the array can have any length.** If n is zero
>   then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible, the array
>   can have any length, and trailing empty strings will be discarded.

Invoking `String#split(String)` is equivalent to invoking

```
yourString.split(yourRegex, 0);
```

which does what that last line of javadoc states, discarding trailing empty strings.

This, however, will not return `null` in the last position of the array returned. It will simply be an empty string.

Comment: Thank you, I had read the JavaDoc, but was a bit confused. You've clarified my confusion. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> There are certain lines that contain no data for the author and are simply blank, however there is still a # at the end. Using Java's built in split, the returned length is only 2.

Yes - there's an empty string before the # and an empty string after it. This is correct.

Probably check whether the strings are empty afterwards. There's a variety of ways to do this.

```
str.isEmpty(); // strings like "  " are not empty
StringUtils.isBlank(str); // strings like "  " are blank
```

If you want to regex the whole thing, try matching `^#*$`, or invert `[^#]`, etc. Regex is probably overpowered. Could use [`StringUtils.indexOfAnyBut("#")`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#indexOfAnyBut).

Comment: @TedHopp for finding "missing author" I'm really hoping the OP can relate my solutions to their problem. If not, woe on them.

Comment: You misread OP's post; it's not the entire line that's blank, only the author field. There's no empty string before the last `#`. There's also no empty string returned by `split` (at least the way OP is using it).

Comment: @TedHopp I updated the quoted section. If the OP is not calling split on a blank line with a # at the end, then I really have no idea what they're talking about and should probably vote to close for unclarity.

Comment: OP's example should have clarified that it's only the author field (after the second `#`) that is blank.

Comment: @TedHopp, if you read through I did specify that it was the authors field that is left blank. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: @Jdsfighter I'm leaving my answer as-is since although you will have to modify it, it is more than enough information to solve your problem.